# Swift - Encoding and Decoding String for special characters

Tags: swift, string, encoding, utf-8, swift3

Here is my problem : I'm currently developping an app including an instant chat (using FCM).
Every thing works except when i try to send special characters like "é" or emojis. 
The push notification received contains the good string but when the discussion is saved on the server and then reloaded, I can't read them and get UTF8 text like "u00ea" for "ê".
I don't really know a lot about encoding etc. but if you guys could help I would be very happy !

Here is the code i use to send a message :

```
    func sendMessage(_ completion: @escaping (_ response: String) -> ()) {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { () -> Void in
        let urlString = //Server adress
        let url = URL(string: urlString)

        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        let set = CharacterSet()
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "Message=" + /*String text to send*/
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot !

PS : I'm new to asking to stackoverflow so don't hesitate to ask for more details

**Edit as asked by Rob** : 
I sent the message "test é è".
The other phone received "test é è" via push notification.
When one phone loads discussion from the server where its stored the answer from the server is.

```
    [{"content":"test u00e9 u00e8","sender":"103","timestamp":"1475491191"}]
```

Also I'm not coding the server, but the guy who is is also making an android app which works really fine with special characters.

**Edit #2** : I also try this code

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        let set = CharacterSet()
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "Message=" + self.message.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: set)!
        let bytesArray = UTF8Encoding.decode(postString)

        request.httpBody = Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(bytesArray), count: bytesArray.count)
```

It does not make any difference.

Thanks a lot for your help guys.

Comment: `U+00EA` is the Unicode code point for "ê". But your presented code looks fine, the problem most probably is somewhere else, like how the data is decoded on the server, stored, loaded or sent back. You'll have to debug each point in the chain! Perhaps JSON is sent back, which could  encode "ê" as `\u00ea`?

Comment: No, the above is not fine. You have to percent escape the `httpBody`. (Also, there's no point in dispatching `dataTask` to a background queue ... it's already asynchronous.)

Comment: @Rob: As far as I know, a HTTP body is just a binary bytes and does not require any special escaping (unless the server requires it).

Comment: True, but I'm inferring from the "Message=" that the server is expecting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request, and if so, then he has to percent escape it. Or do you think he's not using `x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: That is a valid argument. But "u00ea" makes me think that some JSON may be involved.

Comment: @MartinR - I see your point. He may well be confused re JSON response. By the way, FCM uses JSON responses, but the requests are either `x-www-form-urlencoded` or JSON. So we may both be right, that he needs to properly percent escape the request, and he needs to not worry what the response looks like inside the raw JSON response, but rather parse it with `NSJSONSerializer` (or whatever is appropriate with his server) and extract the results from there.

Comment: Alexis, you said "don't hesitate to ask for more details" ... This question is really quite unclear. You should edit your question and show us what the actual response body looked and where you saw this `\u00ea`. If you're looking at raw JSON response or in the debugger, that can be misleading. But we can't advise you further without knowing more about where precisely you saw this `\u00ea` and what precisely the response looked like.

Comment: @Rob I edited the question, hope it can help you understand my problem ! Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure it said `[{"content":"test u00e9 u00e8",...}]`, and not `[{"content":"test \u00e9 \u00e8",...}]`?

Comment: Re your attempt in "edit 2" with `addingPercentEncoding`, you need to set the character set like shown below. You haven't defined what characters are allowed in `set`. And I don't know what that `UTF8Encoding.decode(...)` is, but you should just `postString.data(using: .utf8)` to convert the string to a `Data`.

Comment: @Rob what I print is   `NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as? String` where `data` is the data received from the url session, but yes It is as I said

Comment: OK, if there's no backslash there, then you now have to figure out why. The only thing you want to confirm is that the request is good (so if you can edit your question and show us what the `postString` looks like), but I suspect the lack of backslash is probably some issue with the server implementation.

Comment: This might be related to your question
[App displays text with different characters swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61866522/app-displays-text-with-different-characters-swift/61867049?noredirect=1#comment109781103_61867049)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I think I have it,

As suggested, it was due partially to the server implementation. Due to its security it filtered certain characters and that's why it wasn't working.

We have corrected the problem but it's still doesn't work when the discussion is from iOS to Android or Android to iOS.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Here is my final code :

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = "Message=" + (self.message.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed))!
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
```

Answer (score 8):

You want to use `addingPercentEncoding` to percent escape the string. But don't be tempted to use a character set like `urlQueryAllowed`, as that will let some key characters (notably `&` and `+`) pass unescaped.

As a nice example of how to do this properly, see Alamofire's [ParameterEncoding](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/ParameterEncoding.swift) `escape` routine. Here is a rendition implemented as an extension:

```
extension String {
    public func addingPercentEncodingForQueryParameter() -> String? {
        return addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
    }
}

extension CharacterSet {
    static let urlQueryValueAllowed: CharacterSet = {
        let generalDelimitersToEncode = ":#[]@" // does not include "?" or "/" due to RFC 3986 - Section 3.4
        let subDelimitersToEncode = "!$&'()*+,;="

        var allowed = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
        allowed.remove(charactersIn: generalDelimitersToEncode + subDelimitersToEncode)

        return allowed
    }()
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
func send(message: String, _ completion: @escaping (_ response: String) -> ()) {
    let urlString = ...
    let url = URL(string: urlString)

    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let postString = "Message=\(message.addingPercentEncodingForQueryParameter()!)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        ...
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Send a string with `&` in it, and you should see a difference.

Comment: If you send a message with an ampersand (e.g. "I went to Ben & Jerry's"), you want to make sure that the ampersand makes it all the way through, i.e. that is is properly percent escaped.

Comment: This question is the right one. With this, you can send ampersands.

Comment: Thank you a billion times. <3 Rob

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `Dictionary` to store body for your non-**GET** request (for **POST**, **PUT**, etc.) and use `JSONSerialization` for [encoding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/1413636-data) body in UTF-8 to pass it to `httpBody` of your `URLRequest`.

So instead of:

```
let postString = "Message=" + "Hello, World!"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Use this:

```
let bodyDictionary: [String: Any?] = ["Message": "String text to send"]
request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyDictionary, options: [])
```

Actually it `@available(iOS 5.0, *)` and requires minimum hardcode so it can ensure you to avoid e.g. this "Message **=** " in your code.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply ! However as you can see this is a reaaal old post and it's not really useful anymore.
Anyway, I use Dictionary today :)

Comment: Of course! It's great! Actually I found your question because I was looking for an answer of my own question of similar kind, so I read this and decided to make my own conclusion for you and for everyone who will see this post. Best wishes in your business! :)

Answer (score -1):

try this one! jsonString?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .symbols) ?? ""