# App displays text with different characters swift

Tags: swift, text, label

I am making a chat app. When i send my messages or receive from other user they end up being displayed like this. What might be the issue? It works alright but sometimes it just changes the way the texts are displayed. Am not sure what am missing in this. Can anyone take a look at it. Kindly. Thanks in advance

[image]

Below is my code

```
class ChatController: UIViewController,UITextViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var txtViewBottomConstraints: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var viewTextViewContainer: ViewCustom!
@IBOutlet weak var txtViewContainerHeightConstraints: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var txtViewHeightConstraints: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var lblUserName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var userImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var txtView: IQTextView!
@IBOutlet weak var tblViewChat: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomViewBottomConstraints: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var btnSend: UIButton!


var grpId = String()
var getMessageTimer: Timer!
var scrollEnable : Bool = false
var imagePicker : UIImagePickerController? = nil
var imageData : Data?
var groupName = String()
var groupImage = String()
var isFromNotification = Bool()
var strId = String()
var objChatVM = ChatViewModel()
var getMessageId = String()
var userImage:URL? = nil
var userName = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    popWithSwipe()

    txtView.autocorrectionType = .no
    lblUserName.text = userName
   /* if userImage != nil
    {
    userImg.kf.setImage(with:userImage)
   }
    else
    {
        userImg.image = UIImage(named: "user")
    }*/

    userImg.kf.setImage(with:userImage, completionHandler: {
        (image, error, cacheType, imageUrl) in
        if image != nil{
            self.userImg.image = image
        }
        else{
            self.userImg.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user")
        }

    })


    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = false
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = false

    tblViewChat.dataSource = self
    tblViewChat.delegate = self
    tblViewChat.estimatedRowHeight = 70.0
    tblViewChat.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    txtView.delegate = self

    //  txtView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 2, bottom: 0, right: 2)

    let tapGestuer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestuer)
    tapGestuer.delegate = self


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

            if getMessageTimer != nil{
            getMessageTimer.invalidate()
            }
            getMessageTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(getMessageApi), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = false
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = false

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        getMessageTimer.invalidate()
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)

}

// MARK:- Get messages from server

@objc func getMessageApi(){

     objChatVM.getMessage(param:strId) {status in
     if status{
     self.tblViewChat.reloadData()
     if(self.objChatVM.getNumberOfMessage() != 0){
     self.tblViewChat.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(item: self.objChatVM.getNumberOfMessage()-1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: false)
     }

     }
     }
}


@objc  func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    txtView.resignFirstResponder()
}

// Enable IQKEYBoard manager here for handle keyboard at other  controller which has disabled in viewdidload or viewwillappear

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = true
}


// MARK:- Gesutrue Delegate Methods
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {


    return true
}


// Handle here tap on table view and inside cell for dismiss keyboard while tap outside on the screen

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {

      if (touch.view is SenderTblCell || touch.view is ReceiverTblCell ) {
     return false
     }

     if (touch.view?.superview is SenderTblCell || touch.view?.superview is ReceiverTblCell) {
     return false
     }

     if (touch.view?.superview?.superview is SenderTblCell || touch.view?.superview?.superview is ReceiverTblCell) {
     return false
     }
     if (touch.view?.superview?.superview?.superview is SenderTblCell || touch.view?.superview?.superview?.superview is ReceiverTblCell) {
     return false
     }

     if(touch.view?.superview?.isDescendant(of: SenderTblCell().contentView))! || (touch.view?.superview?.isDescendant(of: ReceiverTblCell().contentView))!{

     return false
     }
    return true // handle the touch

}


// MARK:- KeyBoard will show

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {



    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

        var safeArea = 0
        if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone  ||  UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .pad{
            switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {

            case 2436:
                bottomViewBottomConstraints.constant =  -keyboardSize.height + 30
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            default:


                if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow

                    safeArea = Int(window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0.0)
                }
                bottomViewBottomConstraints.constant =  -keyboardSize.height + CGFloat(safeArea) - 10
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }

}

// MARK:- KeyBoard will hide

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    bottomViewBottomConstraints.constant = -30
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

@IBAction func btnSendAction(_ sender: Any) {


    let param = ["userId":strId,"message":txtView.text!]

    objChatVM.sendMessage(param: param) { (status) in

        self.txtView.text = ""
        self.textViewDidChange(self.txtView)
    }
}

//MARK:- TextView Delegate Methods




func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

    if textView.text == ""{
        //textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        //  txtViewHeightConstraints.constant = 100.0


        //  btnSend.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "attachment"), for: .normal)
    }else{
        // btnSend.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "sendMsg"), for: .normal)
    }

    var frame : CGRect = textView.bounds
    frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height
    print(frame)
    if(frame.height >= 100.0){
        textView.isScrollEnabled = true
    }
    else{
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        txtView.frame.size = frame.size
    }
    if textView.text == ""{

        txtViewContainerHeightConstraints.constant = 50.0
        txtViewBottomConstraints.constant = 5.0
        txtView.updateConstraints()
        viewTextViewContainer.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
        viewTextViewContainer.updateConstraints()
        viewTextViewContainer.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }

}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

}


func textViewShouldEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    return true
}


// MARK:- TableView DataSource and Delegate Methods

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return objChatVM.getNumberOfMessage()
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let messageUserId = objChatVM.getMessageUserFromId(index: indexPath.row)


     print(UserViewModel.Shared().getUserId())

    if(messageUserId == UserViewModel.Shared().getUserId()){

        let cell = tblViewChat.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "senderCell") as! SenderTblCell
        cell.lblMessage.text = objChatVM.getMessage(index: indexPath.row)
        cell.lblDate.text = objChatVM.getDateTime(index: indexPath.row)

        return cell
    }

    let cell = tblViewChat.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "receiverCell") as! ReceiverTblCell
    cell.lblMessage.text = objChatVM.getMessage(index: indexPath.row)
    cell.lblDate.text = objChatVM.getDateTime(index: indexPath.row)
    cell.lblName.text = objChatVM.getFullNameOfUserFrom(index: indexPath.row)
    let url = URL(string:objChatVM.getUserFromImage(index:indexPath.row))
    cell.imgView.kf.indicatorType = .activity
    cell.imgView.kf.setImage(with:url)
    return cell

}




func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {


    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    txtView.resignFirstResponder()
}


// MARK: Side Menu Button Action

@IBAction func btnSideMenuActn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.pushViewControl(ViewControl:"SideMenuController")
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




    }
```

This is how the message from my server in my logs looks like

```
      message = "Am+good.+How+are+you+my+student%3F";
```

Comment: There is too much unnecessary code about your issue. You are percent escaping your data? You could simply unpercent escape it. Where do you send your message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `removingPercentEncoding` and some of the text such as `+` doesn't seem to generated by `urlEncoding` if they are created by code then use both in combination:

```
message = "Am+good.+How+are+you+my+student%3F"
let decodedMessage = message.removingPercentEncoding?.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: " ")
print(decodedMessage)
```

Comment: The issue could be in the format you are sending the code. But, from what you have posted here I can only provide you info on how to handle encoding and decoding.

Comment: I have managed to remove the % signs but i still have the + signs between the spaces

Comment: could you kindly check it again. After adding both codes on '+' sign the %3F is still present